# DRF how to set my model_object_value as key for my object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need the serializer where i can take my file versions with path_to_file like

```
{
   1:path_to_file,
   2: path_to_file,
   .... : ..........,
   n_verison: path_to_file
}
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
    
class ReportVersionInfo(models.Model):

    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.IntegerField()
    file = models.FileField()

    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This means that the model isn't saved to the database yet
        if self._state.adding:
            # Get the maximum display_id value from the database
            last_id = self.objects.all().aggregate(largest=models.Max('version'))['largest']

            # aggregate can return None! Check it first.
            # If it isn't none, just use the last ID specified (which should be the greatest) and add one to it
            if last_id is not None:
                self.version = last_id + 1
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils import timezone

from worker.models import Worker
from report import models

class FileVersionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta: 
        model = models.ReportVersionInfo
        fields = ['version', 'file']
        read_only_fields = ['version']
    

class ReportsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    report_file = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta: 
        
        model = models.Report
        fields = ['employee','file_name', 'report_file',]
```

views.py

```
 class ReportsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = models.Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReportsSerializers
```

i'm newbie on using drf so i apoligize if u think it's stupid question
i tried all examples or any serializermethods, read documention and doesn't find anything which can help me with this

Comment: what's wrong with serializing ```json {
  "report_version_info": {
    "file": "path_to_file",
    "version": "n_version"
  }
}
```

Comment: my json like ` {  id: "file_id" , file_name: "name", versions { there is json which i write on a question  } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response you are proposing would be difficult to understand both from a human perspective and programmatically. The keys should be used to described what the value is, not as values themselves. If I wanted to get the file path from this JSON payload, I couldn't simply access `.path_to_file`, I would need to explicitly know the version number to use as a key to get the data I want.

I would suggest a JSON payload in the following form:

```json
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "employee": "john doe",
      "file_name": "file.pdf",
      "versions": [
        {
          "version": 1,
          "path": "path/to/file"
        },
        {
          "version": 2,
          "path": "/path/to/file"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: do you have any guide about how to do this?

Comment: Since you are using DRF, take a look at [nested objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects). You can nest the `FileVersionSerializer` in the `ReportsSerializer`, and furthermore use the `many=True` keyword for the intended result.

Comment: yes, but i need there should be only 1 version on creation